# Invoices into database : how to store them to make them write-only?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'd like some advice about invoicing and databases.

How should I store customer invoices into database ? 
Since those cannot be modified after being created, I think I should write again all the customer billing informations into the invoice table

```
invoice_table : ... invoice_user_id, invoice_user_name, 
               invoice_user_billing_address ...
```

instead of calling the current "user_id", "user_billing_address", in case the customer changes his informations later.

But it looks like not really efficient.

Is it a better idea to create an invoice table containing only the invoice-relative informations (invoice number, invoice date), and to store the created invoice into a write-only file ?

Comment: If invoices are immutable, then the best option is to have a dedicated table for invoices called `invoice` where you store all relevant information that was valid at the time of creating the invoice, such as customer's address. I don't know what you had in mind about write-only file, but since you are the programmer and the database is yours to command - there's no reason why you would make the invoice table anything than write only (no updates, no deletes).

Comment: Ok I get it. I had in mind something like a pdf file but as Emil said, it is of course worse for efficiency. I was kept into recording an immutable file. Thanks!

Comment: Well, anything that stores data can be altered in a way. If you really want to go down the path where nothing is permitted upon your table, you can enforce so with triggers that deal before/after update/delete. You can have the triggers raise `SQLSTATE` which is effectively an Exception if someone tries to execute UPDATE or DELETE queries on the invoices table. I wouldn't go as far though, but it's an option.

Comment: Ok I keep that in mind. In a legal point of view (although I know it depends on countries), is there a recommanded or compulsory way to record invoices ?

Comment: The only legal stipulation I'm aware of is that you must have record of all the money in and money out and that invoices are supposed to be immutable. As for *how* you perform that - it's up to you. Governments are rarely up to speed with information technologies so it's no wonder that there isn't a legal document describing how to perform invoicing or financial systems to a point where each country / government would be satisfied. If you make invoices immutable and record all the transactions, you are safe (if audit comes along and checks the records, it should match the bank account).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first idea is the preferred way of doing it. Save a copy of the relevant information into columns on the invoice table.

There is no efficiency problems of doing so. In fact, writing some stuff to external files is worse for efficiency. Now you can get all info relating to the invoice in one call.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't seeing things in this way but indeed in a way or another I'll be recording an invoice !